# Plotting PDF and Estimated PDF on the same figure

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram, matlab-figure

I need to plot (bar) both the PDF and the estimated PDF.

Everything starts by generating a uniform random signal.

```
x = random('unif',1,2,1,1000); % between 1 and 2
```

Now to draw the estimated PDF I am using the function **hist**.

```
[N,Mx] = hist(x,10); % 10 intervals
bar(Mx,N);
```

[image]

Now I need to draw the PDF on the same figure. I need to use the function **pdf**.

I tried `P = pdf('unif',linspace(1,2,1000),1,2);`.

But I'm lost between parameters, I need to draw the PDF of x, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to display both the bar graph and the pdf,  you can use the command hold on to plot both simultaneously.

The more complicated part is getting the scaling factor to be comparable for both the experimental and actual pdf. The uniform distribution across a dx of 1 (between 1 and 2) is constantly 1 (since the pdf integrates to 1 over its range). Thus, we need to scale the experimental pdf based on the frequency values we get for each bin. The scale is Nbar/Nsamp. If your dx doesn't equal 1, then this scaling changes is Nbar/(Nsamp*dx)

```
Nsamp = 1000;
Nbar = 10;

xMin = 1;
xMax = 2;
dx = xMax-xMin;

x = random('unif',xMin,xMax,1,Nsamp); 

[N,Mx] = hist(x,Nbar); 
bar(Mx,N/(Nsamp*dx)*Nbar);

P = pdf('unif',linspace(xMin,xMax,Nsamp),xMin,xMax);
hold on;
plot(linspace(xMin,xMax,Nsamp),P,'--r');
hold off
```

Here is the resulting plot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB's [`histogram()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html) function has a *normalization* option which automatically scales to obtain the empirical [pdf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) shape.

Some may find this easier than manual scaling. The command is simple, with very handy inputs and outputs:  `h = histogram(X,'Normalization','pdf')`

[image: Example of histogram function]

```
N = 1000;
a = 1;
b = 2;
X = a + (b-a)*rand(N,1);   % X ~ Uniform(a,b)

figure, hold on, box on
h = histogram(X,'Normalization','pdf','DisplayName','Generated data');
p = plot([a; b],ones(2,1)./(b-a),'r-','DisplayName','U(1,2) PDF');
legend('show','Location','southoutside','Orientation','horizontal');
xlim([1 2]);
```